# Write Pandas DataFrame to newline-delimited JSON

Tags: python, json, pandas

I started by reading a CSV into a Pandas Data Frame via the pandas read_csv() function. Now that the data is in an actual data frame, I tried to write something like this:

```
for row in df.iterrows():
    row[1].to_json(path_to_file)
```

This works but only the last row is saved to disk because I've been rewriting the file each time I make a call to row[1].to_json(path_to_file). I've tried a few other file handling options but to no avail. Can anyone shed some insight on how to proceed?

Thank you!

Comment: Have you got some sample input/output... there's two ways of writing the DF which I can think of might be of use - otherwise, are you just trying to write a specific column?

Comment: A DataFrame is essentially a table representation of data.  What is the structure of the JSON?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can pass a buffer in to `df.to_json()`:

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: df = pd.DataFrame({"a":[1,3,5], "b":[1.1,1.2,1.2]})

In [3]: df
Out[3]: 
   a    b
0  1  1.1
1  3  1.2
2  5  1.2

In [4]: f = open("temp.txt", "w")

In [5]: for row in df.iterrows():
    row[1].to_json(f)
    f.write("\n")
   ...:     

In [6]: f.close()

In [7]: open("temp.txt").read()
Out[7]: '{"a":1.0,"b":1.1}\n{"a":3.0,"b":1.2}\n{"a":5.0,"b":1.2}\n'
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you! If I had 15 reputation I would upvote your answer.

Comment: Glad to help. No need to upvote, you can just accept this answer as correct.

Comment: Noah this is going to be a dumb question but how do I read this back into a Pandas DF? I tried

    with open('jason_lines_file') as f:
        for line in f:
            pd.read_json(line)

Comment: you're best off asking another question; but as a hint, you'll need to do `pd.read_json(line, typ="series")`, and then build a frame from the output

Comment: which raises the question, are you sure this is the format you want to save things into? :)

Comment: I believe the correct answer is of @conradlee - add `lines=True` argument to `to_json` dataframe method.

Comment: Hello, a few years later but I happen to have a question: When exporting the dataframe to a ndjson with your code, there is one field that is supposed to look like this ```/1000/60\"```but the code turns it to ```\/1000\/60\"```. The problem is very difficult to describe but I think its due to string type-rules. Do you know how to solve this? Do I need more parameters in the code from above?

Comment: @John this sounds like expected behavior - maybe worth asking a new question if you're not getting what you'd like?

Answer (score 72):

To create newline-delimited json from a dataframe `df`, run the following

```
df.to_json("path/to/filename.json",
           orient="records",
           lines=True)
```

Pay close attention to those optional keyword args!  The `lines` option was added in pandas `0.19.0`.

Answer (score 3):

If you're trying to write a DF using `iterrows` - I suspect you should be looking at:

```
df.to_json(orient='records') # List of lists of values
# [[1, 2], [3,4]]
```

Or:

```
df.to_json(orient='records') # List of dicts with col->val
# [{'A': 1, 'B': 2}, {'A': 3, 'B': 4}]
```

Or writing a dict of {index:col value}:

```
df.A.to_json()
# {0: 1, 1: 3}
```

Comment: solution #1 df.to_json(orient='records') is perfect except the records are comma separated and I need them to be line separated. Any other suggestions? And I don't understand the difference between your first solution and your second solution - I think they are the same code :)

Comment: @uspowpow You can use with `lines` arg: `df.to_json(orient="records", lines=True)`