# how to write dataframe in JSON in pretty print style?

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe, pretty-print

I want to convert my dataframe to json and dump it in a file in a pretty print format.
I tried -

```
df.to_json(r'C:\users\madhur\Desktop\example.json,'orient = 'index')
```

the above code is dumping in json but in a single line.

I also tried

```
import json
hello = df.to_json(orient = 'index')
with open(r'C:\users\madhur\Desktop\example.json','a') as f:
    json.dump(hello,f,indent=4,sort_keys=True)
```

but the above code is giving a single line output the the output has a `'\'` before the double inverted commas.

the output looks like -

> "{\"17668620_INCOLL\":{\"DRWECNTRY\":\"NEW ZEALAND........"

if some one has any suggestions, answers or need any more information regarding this query then please comment/answer.

Note - I'm using Python 3.6

Comment: Can you post some of your dataframe, some of your data, more of the JSON?

Comment: Related? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28976546/write-pandas-dataframe-to-line-delineated-json

Answer (score 27, accepted):

you can directly pass `indent = int` :

```
df.to_json(r'example.json', orient='index', indent=2 )
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `df.to_dict(orient='records')` if you want to simply be able to copy paste something from REPL